# Animation по очереди

Tags: android, android-animation

У меня есть свой View и используя этот класс создал таких и добавил 7 в `ArrayList`, потом добавил в `RelativeLayout` методом `addView()`. D папке */anim* создал файл анимации.
Мои анимации все за одно появляются, а я хочу чтобы эти `View` появились по очереди, один за другим, через каждые 500 миллисекунд, например .

Как это сделать ?

Comment: ну, по скольку я не знаю подробностей добавления анимации и вообще никаких подробностей, могу предположить, что нужно к анимации добавлять слушатель и в методе onAnimationEnd запускать анимацию для следующей View.

Comment: используя setStartTime() не как нельзя?

Comment: ну можешь конечно рассчитать начало каждой след. анимации на 500 мс позже предыдущей. но я не могу ничего путного сказать, потому что не знаю чем твоя вьюха отличается от всех остальных и ка ты приписываешь ей анимацию.

Comment: простая анимация <translate fromydelta = -20%p toydelta=0 0 0 > я тоже в принципе не разбираюсь .

Comment: но смотрите у меня есть n количество view или n=? и как применить слушатель? for final int i ? или  как?

Comment: ты анимацию как вьюхе добавляешь?

Comment: setAnimation(anim)

Comment: в классе View или в месте где добавляешь вьюхи? если у тебя N их, то ты в цикле это делаешь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете использовать `ObjectAnimator` о дает возможность проигрывать анимации последовательно, или вместе.

Вот пример когда сначала проигрывается одна анимация а потом вторая:

```
ObjectAnimator animator = new ObjectAnimator().ofFloat(progressBar,"progress", 0 ,  mTime);

animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

animator.setDuration(1000);


ObjectAnimator animator2 = new ObjectAnimator().ofFloat(otherView,"progress", 0 ,  mTime);

animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

animator.setDuration(2000);

AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
//проиграть анимации одну за другой
//такой вариант дает возможность комбинировать много анимаций.
set.play(animator).before(animator2);
//тоже самое, только все анимации будут проигрывать по очереди
set.playSequentially(animator,animator2);

set.start();
```

Так же вы можете создавать `ObjectAnimator`  в xml файлах:

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:valueTo="200"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:propertyName="y"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Я встречал то как анимируют одного обьекта ,и два через слущатель ,но не 7 .

Comment: Я умудрился сделать через Хандлер пост делйед, когда принимается для одного обьекта,  то предыдущие анимируются с нынешним.  Не могу сделать так как хочу. По очереди ,и чтобы предыдущие на месте были.  Это ужас

Comment: Я вам показал как можно анимировать вьюхи последовательно, при чем тут "Хандлер пост делйед" ? так как никакого кода в вашем вопросе нету больше ничем помочь не могу!

Comment: В кратце токо:  делаете все свои вью  невидимымы или прозрачными -> добавляете все в контейнер -> начинаете анимацию в контейнере выше указаным способом

Comment: Спасибо...... )))